# How does live video streaming work in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming

How does live video streaming work in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Although I havent tried this but according to web it works

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(URL);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: thanks Toxic, I had also got this piece of code, but what I want to understand is the theory behind the video streaming, ofcourse not the theory behind this code. Like what happens and how about this video streaming. Like video will be transferred part by part, some part will be stored, some decoded or I don't know what and some will be already rendered. Now all these are in very layman terms I want to understand it technically.

Comment: If you look at android documentation its too much incomplete, and that in case of this this VideoView class AFAIK about this is what happens when you pass the url the underlying code of this class automatically starts bufferring the and is decoded based on the codec installed on device ofcourse the it will not wait for the whole file to buffer first and then render it start rendering the the no of complete frames that are buffered, for more info  http://www.techrepublic.com/whitepapers/video-streaming-concepts-algorithms-and-systems/63927

Comment: hmmm.. nice page, but i was looking forward for Android related stuff needed for application level. But anyways thanks a lot for your effort